# navbar-collapse bootstrap show/hide menu issues

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a bit new using Bootstrap and I don't want my menu to show/hide on mouseover but on click.

For instance, I click on a menu, it opens its container, and when I click (not mouseover) elsewhere, it hides.

Thanks

Edited:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li style="width:0px;display:none;" id="smnl">
<div>
<span class='top-header'>
    <span class="header-nl">newsletter</span>
    <span class="header-offer">Offers</span>

</span>

</div></li>


<div style="display:none;">
  <span class="mymenu">
    <span class="sm-tabs-title">our products</span><p>Some text and a form</p>
    </span>
    <span class="mymenu">
    <span class="sm-tabs-title">our services</span><p>Some text and a form</p>
    </span>
<span class="mymenu">
<span class="sm-tabs-title">our contacts</span><p>Some text and a form</p>
   </span>
</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code...

Answer (score 0):

Can you include a minimum working example of your code? It would also help to tell us whether you're on Bootstrap 3.0.3 (the most up-to-date one) or Bootstrap 2.3.2 (an older version).

Since I'm not sure exactly what your problem is, I'll give a more general solution.

Bootstrap's [modal components](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) give beautiful show/hide-on-click functionality, as do [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers). In both scenarios, a separate container is toggled as visible/invisible by pressing a control link (usually a button). Modals are more emphatic than popovers.